# Angular service passing data to controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I am trying to create a service that passes data to controller. 
I cannot see any errors in the console but yet the data won't show. What exactly am I doing wrong?

**Service**

```
app.service('UsersService', function($http, $q) {
  var url = '/users';
  var parsePromise = $q.defer();

  $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
    parsePromise.resolve(data);
  });

  return parsePromise.promise;
});
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('contactsCtrl',
  function($scope, $routeParams, UsersService) {
    // Get all contacts
    UsersService.get().then(function(data) {
      $scope.contacts = data;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

success is now deprecated.

```
app.service('UsersService', function($http) {
  var url = '/users';

  this.get = function() {
      return $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
      });
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you are referring to UsersService.get(), so you must define the .get() function to call:

```
app.service('UsersService', function($http, $q) {
  var url = '/users';

  this.get = function() {
      var parsePromise = $q.defer();

      $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
        parsePromise.resolve(data);
      });

      return parsePromise.promise;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Jesus answer was actually what solved it for me

Comment: I don't understand why this answer is downvoted. It shows you the key reason why the code posted by the OP doesn't work

Comment: @jesuslopez, neither do I.